# Entity Framework - Add or Update Parent Entity with Children

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This code saves an `DomainEntityRecord` (parent) and `DomainEntityDetailRecords` (child), and it works. It feels odd that I get the record from the DB, then remove the entities that don't exist in the domain model version, then when I save, I save (`AddOrUpdate`) the domain entities, and not the EF version. Maybe this is the right way?

```
public void Handle(SaveDomainEntity message)
{
  var domainEntityRecord = mapper.Map<DomainEntityRecord>(message);

  var existingDomainEntity = dbContext.Set<DomainEntityRecord>()
    .Where(x => x.Id == domainEntityRecord.Id)
    .Include(x => x.DomainEntityDetailRecords)
    .SingleOrDefault();

  if (existingDomainEntity != null)
  {
    // Delete detail records that no longer exist.
    foreach (var existingDetail in existingDomainEntity.DomainEntityDetailRecords.ToList())
    {
      if (domainEntityRecord.DomainEntityDetailRecords.All(
        x => x.DetailId != existingDetail.DetailId))
      {
        dbContext.Set<DomainEntityDetailRecord>().Remove(existingDetail);
      }
    }
  }

  dbContext.Set<DomainEntityRecord>().AddOrUpdate(domainEntityRecord);

  domainEntityRecord.DomainEntityDetailRecords.ForEach(
    record => dbContext.Set<DomainEntityDetailRecord>().AddOrUpdate(record));

  dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line ...

> ```
>  dbContext.Set<DomainEntityRecord>().AddOrUpdate(domainEntityRecord);
> ```

... will always try to find an existing record in the database in order to determine whether `domainEntityRecord` should be marked as `Added` or as `Modified`.

But you already fetch the existing record by the statement:

> ```
> var existingDomainEntity = dbContext.Set<DomainEntityRecord>()
>    .Where(x => x.DomainEntityId == domainEntityRecord.DomainEntityId)
>    .Include(x => x.DomainEntityDetailRecords)
>    .SingleOrDefault();
> ```

So there is a redundant database roundtrip in your code. After this statement `var existingDomainEntity = ...` you know everything that `AddOrUpdate` is going to find out again. So you may as well do it yourself: if the record exist: modify it and its details, if it doesn't: add it. To modify the existing records, use `CurrentValues.SetValues`:

```
  var domainEntityRecord = mapper.Map<DomainEntityRecord>(message);

  var existingDomainEntity = dbContext.Set<DomainEntityRecord>()
    .Where(x => x.DomainEntityId == domainEntityRecord.DomainEntityId)
    .Include(x => x.DomainEntityDetailRecords)
    .SingleOrDefault();

  if (existingDomainEntity != null)
  {
    // Delete detail records that no longer exist.
    foreach (var existingDetail in existingDomainEntity.DomainEntityDetailRecords.ToList())
    {
      if (domainEntityRecord.DomainEntityDetailRecords.All(
        x => x.DomainEntityDetailId != existingDetail.DomainEntityDetailId))
      {
        dbContext.Set<DomainEntityDetailRecord>().Remove(existingDetail);
      }
    }
    // Copy current (incoming) values to db entry:
    dbContext.Entry(existingDomainEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(domainEntityRecord);
    var detailPairs = from curr in domainEntityRecord.DomainEntityDetailRecords
                      join db in existingDomainEntity.DomainEntityDetailRecords 
                        on curr.DomainEntityDetailId equals db.DomainEntityDetailId into grp
                      from db in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { curr, db };
    foreach(var pair in detailPairs)
    {
      if (pair.db != null)
        dbContext.Entry(pair.db).CurrentValues.SetValues(pair.curr);
      else
        dbContext.Set<DomainEntityDetailRecord>().Add(pair.curr);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    dbContext.Set<DomainEntityRecord>().Add(domainEntityRecord);
    // This also adds its DomainEntityDetailRecords
  }

  dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

As you see, for the details I use a `GroupJoin` (`join - into` which serves as an outer join) to determine the existing and the new details. The existing ones are modified, the new ones are added.

Comment: That's an excellent point about the unnecessary DB trip. I'll apply these improvements tonight or tomorrow and then accept/upvote this answer. Thanks!

Comment: I tried fixing two typos, but I got an error that the code wasn't formatted properly. Tried to fix, but still wouldn't take. The `foreach` should use `detailPairs`, not just `pairs`. And the `Add` a couple of lines later should use `pair.curr`, not just `curr`.

Comment: Also, when there is a new detail record, I don't think the join is recognizing it. The existing three details get updated, but the new detail doesn't get added. Looking into that now...

Comment: Got it. Needed `DefaultIfEmpty()` here: `from db in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: Thank you for your patient scrutiny! I typed it off the top of my head and a couple of mistakes sneaked in.

Comment: I used SQL Profiler to check out the difference between my original code and the code in this answer. They each generate 5 updates (1 header, 4 detail). However, my original code also generates a `SELECT TOP 2...` for each `AddOrUpdate()`. So these findings confirm what Gert said. The original code has 5 extra `SELECT` statements; one for each `AddOrUpdate()`. Good stuff.

Comment: By the way, `SELECT TOP 2...` is so that EF can throw an exception if more than one record is found.

Comment: Gert, I need your answer edited to change all the variable names, like I did in my question. I tried editing your answer, but no matter what I do, I get: "your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code," even when I try to save without making changes. My team has suggested I don't post my actual variable names in a public forum. If you can edit the post, that would be nice. If not, I'll need to delete it.